# Bar plot of two columns in x-axis in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

My dataset is called `df`:

| year | french | flemish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 200 | 200 |
| 2015 | 170 | 210 |
| 2016 | 130 | 220 |
| 2017 | 120 | 225 |
| 2018 | 210 | 250 |

I want to create a histogram in seaborn with `french` and `flemish` on the x-axis and `year` as the hue.

I tried this, but it didn't work successfully:

```py
sns.histplot(data=df, x="french", hue="year", multiple="dodge", shrink=.8)
```

The y-axis should show the height of the number of the columns of `french` and `flemish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use a bar function, not a histogram function. Histogram functions take raw data and count them, but your data are already counted.
2. You need to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the `french` and `flemish` columns into "[long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-data)." Then `x` will be the language, and `y` will be the counts.

```py
sns.barplot(data=df.melt("year", var_name="language", value_name="count"),
            x="language",
            y="count",
            hue="year")
plt.legend(loc=(1.05, 0))
```

[image]

---

The melted dataframe for reference:

```py
>>> df.melt("year", var_name="language", value_name="count")

#    year  language  count
# 0  2014    french    200
# 1  2015    french    170
# 2  2016    french    130
# 3  2017    french    120
# 4  2018    french    210
# 5  2014   flemish    200
# 6  2015   flemish    210
# 7  2016   flemish    220
# 8  2017   flemish    225
# 9  2018   flemish    250
```